# How to reference an Eclipse locally deployed spring app from Angular?

Tags: angular, spring, eclipse, tomcat

There is a `Spring` project deployed on an `Eclipse` local server ( based on `Tomcat` ).

I want to reference this project from `Angular`. I tried `http://localhost:8083/gmao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/gmao/` , then `http://localhost:8083/gmao/` but both does not work.

So how to reference the Spring project ?

Comment: In what way does it not work? At all, even from the CLI using something like `curl`? Just from Angular? If so, do your in-browser tools show connection failure messages?

Answer (score 0):

Websites are restricted to accessing resources from the same origin through what is known as same-origin policy. Therefore, you need to enable **CORS [Cross-origin resource sharing]** as to connect FrontEnd(Angular) and BackEnd(Java) that are running on different ports.

In spring, you can do something like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

This will enable CORS requests from your Angular application (running on port 4200) to any endpoint in the Spring application.

Another simple way is to add **@CrossOrigin** at Controller/Class level or API method level in Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

I hope this answers your question